# Convert list of lists of bs4.element.ResultsSets into a list of strings

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

As I am working on scraping a website, I have found myself with a list of lists containing bs4.element.ResulstSets from a find_all() search. Therefore the output of my variable (features) looks like this

```
[[<li class="WlSsj">Terrasse</li>],
[<li class="WlSsj">Balkon</li>, <li class="WlSsj">Video Live-Besichtigung</li>],
[<li class="WlSsj">Balkon</li>, <li class="WlSsj">Terrasse</li>],
[],
[<li class="WlSsj y7k9g">Neubauprojekt</li>, <li class="WlSsj">Garten</li>, <li class="WlSsj">Balkon</li>, <li class="WlSsj">Terrasse</li>]]
```

I would now like to turn this into a list of strings like this:

```
["Terrasse",
"Balkin, Video-Besichtigung",
"Balkon, Terrasse",
"",
"Neubauprojekt, Garten, Balkon, Terrasse"]
```

I have tried many things but sometimes the empty list is not converted to an empty string or the order is not consistent.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested `for` loops and extract the text of that element, in your case:

```
inner_text = list()
# features is the list of lists you get with bs4
for lis in features:
    text_to_append = ""
    for item in lis:
        text_to_append = f"{text_to_append}, {item.text}"
    
    inner_text.append(text_to_append)
```